# How to use the output of an r function in another function?

Tags: r, function, nested

I want to create an script that calculates probabilities for a rol game.

I´m new to programming and I´m stuck with the return values and nested functions. What I want is to use the values returned by the first function in the next one.

I have two functions `dice(k, n)` and `fight(a, b)`. (for the example, the functions are partly written):

```
dice <- function (k, n) {
  if (k > 3 && n > 2){
    a <- 3
    b <- 2
    attack <- sample(1:6, a)
    deff <- sample(1:6, b)
    }
    return(c(attack, deff))
}
```

So I want to use the vector `attack`, and `deff` in the next function:

```
fight <- function(a, b){
  if (a == 3 && b == 2){
    if(sort(attack,T)[1] > sort(deff,T)[1]){
      n <- n - 1}
    if (sort(attack,T)[1] <= sort(deff,T)[1]) {
      k <- k - 1}
    if (sort(attack,T)[2] > sort(deff,T)[2]) {
      n <- n - 1}
    if (sort(attack,T)[2]<= sort(deff,T)[2]){
      k <- k - 1}
  }
  return(c(k, n)
}
```

But this gives me the next error:
`Error in sort(attack, T) : object 'attack' not found`

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at `str(dice(4,3))`: you function `dice()` returns only one vector. Use in the definition of your function dice() `return(list(attac=attac, deff=deff))` So you can use the elements of the result: `L <- dice(4,3); L$attac; L$deff`

Comment: Looks like the game of Risk. In your second function `return(c(k, n)` has unbalanced parentheses.